# Combine arrays that have same value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have array like this

```
$arr=[["a","b"],["b","c"],["d","e"],["f","c"]];
```

if sub arrays share same value they should be be merged to one array

expected output:

```
$arr=[["a","b","c","f"],["d","e"]];
```

I`m trying to avoid doing foreach inside foreach for solving this.

Comment: A) Show us some code. B) Is this per key or per key=>value pair?

Comment: Try recursion instead of iteration. Consider input array like `$arr=[["a","b"],["d","e"],["f","g"],["b","c"],["d","c"]];`

Comment: Your expected output does not make sense?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is solution I get for now.

```
    $arr=[["a","b","c","f"],["d","e"]];
    $sortedArray = sortFunction($arr,0,array());

function sortFunction($old,$index,$new) {
    if ($index == sizeof($old)) return $new;

    for ($i = 0; $i<sizeof($new); $i++) {
        if (count(array_intersect($new[$i],$old[$index]))) {
            $new[$i] = array_unique(array_merge($old[$index],$new[$i]), SORT_REGULAR);
            return sortFunction($old,$index + 1,$new);
        }
    }

    $new[] = $old[$index];
    return sortFunction($old,$index + 1,$new);
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your inner arrays always have 2 items. so nested loops aren't necessary. Here is a solution which I originally wrote in JS but it should work just as good and **most efficient** in PHP:

```
$arr=[["a","b"],["b","c"],["d","e"],["f","c"],["h","e"]];
$output = [];
$outputKeys = [];
$counter = 0;
foreach($arr as $V) {
    if(!isset($outputKeys[$V[0]]) && !isset($outputKeys[$V[1]])) {
        $output[$counter] = [$V[0], $V[1]];
        $outputKeys[$V[0]] = &$output[$counter];
        $outputKeys[$V[1]] = &$output[$counter];
        $counter++;
    }
    elseif(isset($outputKeys[$V[0]]) && !isset($outputKeys[$V[1]])) {
        array_push($outputKeys[$V[0]], $V[1]);
        $outputKeys[$V[1]] = &$outputKeys[$V[0]];
    }
    elseif(!isset($outputKeys[$V[0]]) && isset($outputKeys[$V[1]])) {
        array_push($outputKeys[$V[1]], $V[0]);
        $outputKeys[$V[0]] = &$outputKeys[$V[1]];
    }
}
var_dump($output); // [["a","b","c","f"],["d","e","h"]]
```

[DEMO (click the execute button)](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/21989f9216dc41dab0549d7fe3fca7b0a2803f06)

Pointers are your friends. Use them :)

Answer (score 0):

The following algorithm should do what you want. It simply checks through each item and checks if it already exists in the newly created array, and if it does it adds it to that item instead of a new one:

```
<?php

$arr=[["a","b"],["b","c"],["d","e"],["f","c"]];

$newArr = [];

foreach ($arr as $items) {
    $newKey = null;

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        foreach ($newArr as $newItemsKey => $newItems) {
            if (in_array($item, $newItems)) {
                $newKey = $newItemsKey;

                break 2;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($newKey !== null) {
        $newArr[$newKey] = array_merge($newArr[$newKey], $items);
    } else {
        $newArr[] = $items;
    }
}

$newArr = array_map('array_unique', $newArr);

print_r($newArr);
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [3] => c
            [4] => f
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => d
            [1] => e
        )

)
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/532011)

Comment: thanks, but as i said I was trying to avoid nested loops.

Comment: @AlexKneller Any particular reason? How many items are you dealing with?